# Display ID in table as another Name/phrase

Tags: html, angularjs

I am wondering if there is a way to display for example an id in a table cell as another name from another object as their id's correspond to each other.

What i want to do is to display it in a way like this if there is something similar?

```
<td class="tableRowText"><p>{{l.SenderId}}</p></td>
```

in a way like this.

```
ng-options="x.ProcessId as x.Name for x in PL"
```

so that would be something like:

```
<td class="tableRowText"><p>{{l.SenderId}} as x.Name for x in PL</p></td>
```

WISHFULLY! :P hope you guys understand i'm just trying to get my point through.

Thanks in advance!

_____________EDIT:_______________________________

So this is the Table and how i request the data.

```js
app.factory('getTableGridDataService', function ($resource, config) {
    return $resource(config.apiURL + '/Logs/GetLogEvents', {}, { 'post': { method: 'POST' } })
});



scope.loggItems = [];
    $scope.fillRealTable = function () {
        var arrayBody = {          
            Sending: $scope.paramSending,
            Receiving: $scope.paramReceiving,
            Logging: $scope.paramLogging,
        };
        var query = postTableGridDataService.post({}, arrayBody);
        query.$promise.then(function (data) {
            var loggItemList = data;
   
            $scope.loggItems = loggItemList
        })
    }
```

```html
<table class="table table-striped table-condensed table-hover" id="MainTable">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th ng-click="sort('SenderId')" style="cursor:pointer;">
    Sender
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort" ng-show="sortKey=='SenderId'" ng-class="{'glyphicon glyphicon-menu-up':reverse, 'glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down':!reverse}"></span>
   </th>

   <th ng-click="sort('ReceiverId')" style="cursor:pointer;">
    Reciever
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort" ng-show="sortKey=='ReceiverId'" ng-class="{'glyphicon glyphicon-menu-up':reverse, 'glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down':!reverse}"></span>
   </th>

   <th ng-click="sort('LoggingId')" style="cursor:pointer;">
    Logging source
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort" ng-show="sortKey=='LoggingId'" ng-class="{'glyphicon glyphicon-menu-up':reverse, 'glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down':!reverse}"></span>
   </th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr dir-paginate="l in loggItems.LogEventList|filter:search|orderBy:sortKey:reverse|itemsPerPage:15" pagination-id="mainPagination">

   <td class="tableRowText"><p>{{l.SenderId}}</p></td>
   <td class="tableRowText"><p>{{l.ReceiverId}}</p></td>
   <td class="tableRowText"><p>{{l.LoggingId}}</p></td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

I also get another object from my api in which i have the names for the Sending-ID, Reciever-ID and Logging-ID and i want those names displayed in the table instead of the id's from my Object in wich i display in the tabl. how do i achieve that?

The other object with the corresponding ID's and names:

```js
app.factory('getSearchFormData', function ($resource, config) {
    return $resource(config.apiURL + '/SearchFormObj/getSearchFormItems', {} ,{'get': {method:'GET'}})
});


$scope.SL = [];
function SearchData() {
  var query = getSearchFormData.get();
  query.$promise.then(function (data) {
    $scope.SL = data.SystemList;
    console.log($scope.SL);
  });
};
SearchData()
```

Here is the object returned from getSearchFormData:

[image: returned Data]

Comment: I'm confused on what you are asking. Can you post some example data? Are you saying you have two sets of data where the ID is in common and you want to display the name from one set of data where the ID is the same in the other set? Is the set without the name the data for an `ng-repeat` for the `tr`?

Comment: what i am trying to do is having a ID (that is placed in a cell in one of my table rows) displayed as its corresponding name (that exists in a other object) is it possible to change the visual side so that the id in the table displays the name instead dynamically?

Comment: There are a few different ways to go about it. Can you post some example data so I can give you a better idea of how to approach it?

Comment: I will post some examples as soon as i get home, Thanks for taking the time machinehead115. :)

Comment: There we go Edited.

Comment: Can you provide the data structure of the objects one of those IDs corresponds to?

Comment: oh sorry forgot those.

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is in your controller which depends on both services, you wait for both promises to resolve, then loop through your log items and either replace the ids with the names, or add then names to each log item, if you want to keep the ids.

```
$scope.fillRealTable = function () {
    var arrayBody = {          
        Sending: $scope.paramSending,
        Receiving: $scope.paramReceiving,
        Logging: $scope.paramLogging,
    };
    var p1 = postTableGridDataService.post({}, arrayBody).$promise;
    var p2 = getSearchFormData.get().$promise;

    //it might be $q.all([p1.promise,p2.promise])
    $q.all([p1,p2]).then(function(data1, data2) {
        var loggItemList = data1;
        var SL = data2.SystemList;

        loggItemList.forEach(function (item) {
            item.SenderName = SL[item.SenderId].name;
            item.ReceiverName = SL[item.ReceiverId].name;
            item.LogginName = SL[item.LogginId].name;
        });

        $scope.loggItems = loggItemList;
    });
}
```

The code in the forEach is all speculation, since you do not provide the structure of the data returned by `getSearchFormData`, so this example assumes it's key-value list of objects with the key being one of the ID. E.g:

```
{
  "A001" : { name: "John Smith" },
  "B001" : { name: "Bruce Wayne" }
}
```

---

P.S: An alternative to this method is to move the whole mapping in `getTableGridDataService` and have that service call the other, meaning your view logic remains simple, since it will receive the full result from the service.